# grey strikes strokes through folders in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been working with this project for some time.
Today grey strikes appeared through the folders of one project (PhoneStreamingActivity).
Why?
I was wiring up the jni component of my project and moving some files between packages when it happened.

[image]

Comment: Eclipse has a tendency of being a pain in the neck sometimes, and doing weird stuff. Have you tried upgrading to Eclipse Juno? That worked for me for some of my frustrations.

Comment: This is with Juno :).  I tried the usual close and re-open.  No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this website grey bars mean method is deprecated. Perhaps something in the folder is deprecated.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

Comment: Good tip.  I'd been looking for a listing of icon meanings in eclipse with no luck.  Your hint did help me fix some deprecated functions.  However, the grey strikes didn't go away when i fixed them.